# Rails 3 current user id to comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So Im working on a rails app where users can comment on photos or videos another user has uploaded and so far everything is great except I am not able to get the current user_id associated with the person who has commented on the post. This is what I have so far.

user.rb

```
has_many :comments,  :dependent => :destroy
```

photo.rb

```
has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
```

video.rb

```
has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
```

comments_controller.rb

```
def create
  @commentable = find_commentable
  @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment])
 if @comment.save
   redirect_to :id => nil, :notice => "Successfully created comment."
 else
   render :action => 'new'
 end
end
```

How can I get the user id to appear with the current comments? I have the comment type and comment id I am just looking for a way to have it so the user_id can appear. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have the comment object, it's probably as simple as `comment.user.id`, but perhaps you should include your comment model in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add a [hidden_field](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field) to your form partial where you store the current_user.id

something like:

```
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
```

of course you should have a field `user_id` in your comment model, as a comment belongs_to user and a user has_many comments.

**update:**

what ofca pointed out, this can approach can lead to security issues as the hidden field could be modified by the user in the browser, e.g. using firebug.
In this case it is probably better to to leave out this field in the view and create the comment in the controller by using

```
<%= current_user.comments.create(params[:comment]) %>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I added the above code to code and everything works.

Comment: isn't this not the best practice as someone could fiddle with user_id param since it has to be mass acessible?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it now, it is only set up one way.
Plus you have to make it polymorphic
try adding:

comment.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
```

Comment: The code you have above is already posted in the comment.rb file. Everything works find Im just unsure how to call the current_user with the `@comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment])`. I would like to see the user id of the user who has posted the comment.<br/> I would have done this to get just the user `@comment = current_user.commentss.build(params[:comment])` but then I am missing the commentable.

Comment: im's sorry, it is not completly clear to me what you want to do. Are you trying to create a new command and wonder how to add it to the current user, or are you trying to just get the user given a comment, or ...?